# is there a winapi call for selecting rectangle in console?

Tags: windows, winapi, console, textselection

here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683173(v=vs.85).aspx - I found only `GetConsoleSelectionInfo()` and that is only console function that has 'select' in its name. But what about setting programatically selection rectagle with custom parameters ?

Comment: Seeing as that operation is primarily for copying to the clipboard, can;t you just copy the data to the clipboard directly?

Comment: yes, but there is a burden of selecting with a mouse line that may be extending over the border of conosole window. Copying is easy but selecting is cumbersome. I thought of writing a function that would select given line, and only wait for user to press enter to copy that line to clipboard.